# Piping command string to AutoHotkey hangs in pwsh but not powershell

Tags: autohotkey, powershell-core

The following command does not block, but doesn't maximize the window desired:

```
 'WinMaximize, ahk_class ENMainFrame' | D:\tools\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe *
```

It leaves a background process running:

```
PS D:\projects> ps auto*

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
     11     1.73       7.56       0.00   11000   1 AutoHotkey
```

This background process hangs without maximizing the window for 7+ minutes if the terminal is left alone. However, if I hold down the ENTER key, (displaying a series of new prompts), within a few seconds the targeted window will be maximized and the background process will terminate. Similarly, I can type `.\` and then hold TAB for a few seconds (cycling through file name completions) with the same effect.

This behavior is present with:

- `pwsh` (7.0.3) with ConEmu
- `pwsh` (7.0.3) with traditional Windows Terminal UI
- `pwsh -NoProfile` (7.0.3)

But not present with:

- `powershell` (5.1.18362.752, after adjusting the default encoding)
- `cmd`

Similarly, the following command seems to work correctly and execute immediately:

```
 'WinMaximize, ahk_class ENMainFrame' | D:\tools\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe * &
```

Any ideas? This seems like a bug to me with pwsh's thread handling maybe.